# SpringBoot Java Linux

Tags: java, linux, docker, spring-boot

While trying to Dockerize SpringBoot Application I ran into this line of commands

`ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/sample.jar"]`

I know its trying to execute the jar file. What I don't know much about is the second argument:-

`-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom`

I have googled quiet a bit but didn't find a good answer. Also the help menu in command line for java didn't do much. Can anyone elaborate this particular argument to me and other people who are in the same boat. Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: http://www.thezonemanager.com/2015/07/whats-so-special-about-devurandom.html

Comment: Check this http://ruleoftech.com/2016/avoiding-jvm-delays-caused-by-random-number-generation

Answer (score 0):

java.security.egd use for override parameter securerandom.source in JVM security file.

Please see this link for more information

http://ruleoftech.com/2016/avoiding-jvm-delays-caused-by-random-number-generation

Answer (score -1):

I think you will get best description on original bug reported https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4705093

check this out.